# foreach loop in a form to save values

Tags: laravel

I try to save two values from text field but actually with this view when i click on save i get only the first ID of the foreach.

the two text field are : resultat_domicile and resultat_visiteur i would like to get the values foreach objects

someone know how to achieve this ? thanks a lot in advance

here my view :

```
@foreach($rencontres as $rencontre)

                    {!!  Form::open(array('route' => array('add.resultat', $rencontre->id)))!!}

                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <h2 class="pull-right"><div class="fa fa-shield pull-right"></div>{{$rencontre->equipe_domicile->lb_equipe}}</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                                        {!! Form::text('resultat_domicile', null ,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ex: 20 points']) !!}

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                                        <span class="h2">-</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                                        {!! Form::text('resultat_visiteur', null ,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ex: 20 points']) !!}
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <h2 class="pull-left"><div class="fa fa-shield pull-left"></div>{{$rencontre->equipe_visiteur->lb_equipe}}</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-info btn-lg center-block']) !!}
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        @endforeach
```

here my controller :

```
public function addResultat(Request $request  , $id){

        $rencontre = Rencontre::findOrFail($id);

        $rencontre->resultat_domicile = $request->input('resultat_domicile');
        $rencontre->resultat_visiteur = $request->input('resultat_visiteur');

        dd($rencontre);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're not only retrieving the LAST of the 'recontres'? When you create those form elements with the names 'resultat_domicile' and 'resultat_visiteur', you are overwriting which field gets sent to the request.

If you put a [] after the name, then they will be an array of values when they get sent to the request.

For example, this would be:

```
{!! Form::text('resultat_domiciles[]', ...
```

Comment: yes i get the first id object of the query. so when i click on Save the two button save form the view seems to be check in the same time and i get only the first object . maybe my foreach loops are not in the right place ?